# How to Open Word file in browser using asp.net on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Every time file is downloading instead of open in new tab. My code is:

```
protected void bttnpdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilePath = Server.MapPath("Road map.docx");
    WebClient User = new WebClient();
    Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
    if (FileBuffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = " application/vnd.openxmlformats-
        officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't open a .docx in a new tab. Browsers understand HTML/CSS/JS etc. Not DOCX. You would need to write a plugin for the browser or otherwise create some library to render the DOCX as HTML. Both of which are non-trivial.

Comment: You cannot open word files directly from the browser without some plugin or extension